# Deploying Cordova app to iOS devices through ad hoc distribution

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

I have a finished Cordova app, ready to be tested by a client. Everything works fine with `cordova run ios` and `cordova build ios --release` succeeds. I've set up my iOS Certificate, Provisioning Profile and added my Devices to it. Where do I go from here? I can't find any files that Apple's Application Loader will accept. Do I have more steps to do through Cordova? Or do I have to delve into Xcode? I've read numerous guides and can't wrap my head around what's going on.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add your devices before or after you downloaded the provisioning-profile?

Comment: I added the devices before creating the profile.